# How can I get UIPickerView to select the first item?

Tags: objective-c

I am encountering a funny problem with UIPickerView. My data source has 2 items:

"All" and "Home"

When I select one, I execute a certain task.

By default All is selected. When I click on Home my task executes, and then when I choose the picker again, it is set to All. In order to select All, I have to scroll up a bit, so that the selection is off All, and then let go so it falls back down to All.

What is the best way to be able to select All?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIActionSheet fits better here.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is to call:

```
[myPickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
```

That'll actually DO the selection action, and fire it as if it was just chosen. If you wanted, you could make it roll to the thing visually by saying `animated:YES`, but you probably don't really want that, you just want to initialize the picker and fire the first option.

Comment: What would happen if the picker view is empty ((0, 0) would be out of bounds)? Will it crash?

Comment: @WTP Yeah, probably. You want to do this only after you've populated the thing.